# Postgres Distinct Shorthand

Tags: postgresql

Instead of an expression

```
a <> e or b <> f or c <> g
```

Is there any shorthand statement or function kind of

```
distinct (a, b, c) to (e, f, g)
```

Comment: `(a, b, c) <> (e, f, g)`?

Comment: Wah! That's as amazing as simple)) thx @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in comment above

```
(a, b, c) <> (e, f, g)
```

Never knew that notation.
Thx.

P.s. And actually I've found another statement (I was so close)

```
(a, b, c) is distinct from (e, f, g)
```

which works fine as well. Still simple `<>` comparison looks more obvious any way.

Comment: Just note, that ```<>``` behaves different with ```NULL``` in comparison to ```IS DISTINCT FROM```. The first yields ```NULL``` if at least one of the compared values is ```NULL```. The second yields ```false``` if only one of the operands is ```NULL``` while ```NULL IS DISTINCT FROM NULL``` yields ```true``` (so it never yields ```NULL```).

Comment: `<>` is wrong and `IS DISTINCT FROM` is correct. `(1, NULL, 3) <> (1, NULL, 3)` is *not* false.